# Why is my home directory encrypted and inaccessible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, home-directory

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu Server because I want to learn Linux and I want to learn about servers. I did a newbie tutorial and then shut down. When I booted up today, the files in my home directory were replaced by Access-your-private-data.desktop and readme.txt, but I have no idea why. I followed the instructions in readme.txt and typed ecryptfs-mount-private. It told me

```
INFO: Your private directory has been mounted.
INFO: To see this change in your current shell:
cd /home/rmob
```

But if I do ls /home/rmob, it still shows me Access-your-private-data.desktop and readme.txt instead of the files I created there yesterday. Every time I reboot, it tells me

```
keyctl_search: Required key not available
Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'
```

If I try ecryptfs-mount-private again, it still tells me it has mounted it, but still just shows me those same two files.

Googling about this tells me this means the directory got encrypted somehow. I tried typing touch ~/.ecryptfs/auto-mount which I found in [this tutorial](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/Ecryptfs), but it didn't make a difference and I can't find any other solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

During the setup steps, it prompts you on whether you'd like to encrypt your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation, there was a question asking if you wanted to encrypt your home folder. I usually select no to this and do my own encryption (TrueCrypt) as I prefer this method over Ubuntu's built in one.

I do not know much about Ubuntu's built in encryption, but if You've not gone through much initial configuration and wanting to learn more about the installation process, a format too much out of the question?